# How to convert a ISingleResult<T> containing a string to a string array

Tags: .net, arrays, linq

I am tempted to loop through the results and just add it to the string array but I'm sure there must be a better way.

My sproc returns a `ISingleResult<T>`  (where T is just a class with 1 string).

I want to return this list as a string[].  Is there any way to do this without using foreach loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ISingleResult inherits IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534556.aspx)

IEnumerable has an extension method called [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx).

**Edit** sorry,  missed that T was a class, not String. So it would be

```
ISingleResultValue.Select(x=>x.StringProperty).ToArray();
```